# How to pass variable value to another file via class'

Tags: php, class, include

I have my main (user visible) file which displays posts, and I need to set-up pagination.

It would be easy if I fetch DB in the same file (but I want to avoid that), that is why I created a seperate (user hidden) file which contains class' which are then called from main file(blog.php):

BLOG.php(simplified):

```
<?php
require 'core.php';

$posts_b = new Posts_b();
$posts_bx = $posts_b->fetchPosts_b();

foreach($posts_hx as $posts_hy){

   echo $posts_hy['title'];
}
?>
```

core.php(simplified);

```
class Posts_b extends Core {
public function fetchPosts_b(){

    $this->query ("SELECT posts_id, title FROM posts"); 

//return
return $this->rows();

    }
}
```

This works like a charm, but now I need to do the count within query, which works fine, and which gives me a variable $pages=5 (handled inside class posts_b - in file core.php),

core.php(simplified-with variable);

```
class Posts_b extends Core {
public function fetchPosts_b(){

    $this->query ("SELECT posts_id, title FROM posts"); 
    $pages=5;   

//return
return $this->rows();

    }
}
```

Now I need a way to return this variable value to blog.php (the way I return rows())

Please help, anyone,

Thank you...

Comment: So the question is, how do I pass the variable $pages back to blog.php along with $this->rows() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can only have a single return value.

There are ways to get around this though.  You can make your return value be an array that contains all of the values you want. For example:

```
return array("pages"=>$pages, "rows"=>$this->rows());
```

Then in your code

```
require 'core.php';

$posts_b = new Posts_b();
$posts_bx = $posts_b->fetchPosts_b();
$pages = $posts_bx["pages"];
foreach($posts_hx["rows"] as $posts_hy){

   echo $posts_hy['title'];
}
?>
```

Or you can adjust a input parameter provided it was supplied as a reference

```
public function fetchPosts_b(&$numRows){

  $this->query ("SELECT posts_id, title FROM posts"); 

  //return
  return $this->rows();

}
```

In your code

```
require 'core.php';

$posts_b = new Posts_b();
$pages = 0;
$posts_bx = $posts_b->fetchPosts_b(&$pages);

foreach($posts_hx["rows"] as $posts_hy){

   echo $posts_hy['title'];
}
?>
```

Or you can opt to figure out your pagination outside of the fetchPosts_b method.

```
$posts_bx = $posts_b->fetchPosts_b();
$pages = floor(count($posts_bx)/50);
```

Comment: Tried the first solution and it works like a charm. Thank you very much. 
p.s. I made a writing mistake (while writing a question) insted posts_hx it was bx (but the general ide is the same)...